# RethinkDB remote client connection without exposing admin web interface to everybody

Tags: rethinkdb

Rethink 1.6. I'm trying to connect to a remote server running rethinkdb from a different server running client (ruby, python) only and it works only if bind=all but that exposes web admin to everybody which I want to avoid.

I've tried with and without auth_key and only works with bind=all
I've also tried to specify my remote server address (i.e bind=127.0.0.1, 199.199.3.5) but it does not work (parse) on the rethink server level

Thanks

Comment: What OS are you using?  Linux? if so, have you thought about an IP Tables rule to limit who can access that port by IP?

Comment: ubuntu 12.04 server. Looks like that is the only option at the moment. I don't know much about iptables rules, I'l have to learn now I guess. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

replace 5.5.5.5 with the IP of the server that should be able to access the web interface.  Replace 2222 with the port the web interface runs on.

```
#!/bin/sh

iptables -F
iptables -X

# Default rules
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -o lo -j ACCEPT

# rethinkdb
iptables -A INPUT -s 5.5.5.5 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2222 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 5.5.5.5 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 2222 -j ACCEPT

# We allow TCP and UDP connections already established to enter
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

After you do this save your config to a file

```
sudo sh -c "iptables-save > /etc/iptables.rules"
```

Edit your network interfaces file so the rules will be re-applied on reboot

```
sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces
```

Add the pre-up rule so it looks similar to below

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
  pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules
```

Comment: Thanks Nick. Too many things on the go right now, but I'll definitely come back to it later and try your solution.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create **proxy server** and expose web ui for public only with conditions (security), in rethinkdb documentation it is already mentioned how to do it with apache server, but honestly it is not practical.

if you are using node.js (expressjs or connect) this is how you can integrate rethink db web ui inside your web application under a custom url via reverse proxy for example http://example.com/rethinkdb

```
// Configure Proxy Servers
var proxy = require('proxy-middleware');
// Server 1: rethinkdb
var rethinkdb = proxy('http://localhost:8080/');
var rethinkdb_path = "/rethinkdb";
app.use(rethinkdb_path, function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.originalUrl === rethinkdb_path) return res.redirect(301, rethinkdb_path + "/");
    // add your own security here ;)
    if (req.isAuthenticated() && req.user.email === "digital.flowers@hotmail.com") {
        return rethinkdb(req, res, next);
    }
    next();
});
```

of course you need to install proxy-middleware nodejs module via `npm install proxy-middleware --save`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using iptables as described by Nick above, you can also put a reverse proxy in front of the web UI to make it accessible via a password. We (RethinkDB) will be writing up a doc on how to do that soon, but you can find out how to do this on Google pretty easily.

Sorry for authentication woes, we'll make this clearer soon.